# Delete list column for search results (Sharepoint online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I do not want to include the column "Created by" searches within a list, for this, I've tried the following:

1. Within Sharepoint Administration Center, Manage search scheme, managed properties, find the column "created by" and check the "Allow search" option is unchecked.
2. Sharepoint Administration Center, Manage search scheme, and look for the `ows_Created_x0020_By` column within the crawled properties and eliminate the allocation to managed property `CreatedBy`. Attempt uncheck the `Include in the full-text index` but is not enabled.
3. I enter the list within the advanced options, and click in the "Reindex list" option.
4. I wait several days for next scheduled crawl, but searches for the field "Created by" continue returning results.

Is it enough to remove the relationship between crawled and managed property? How I can allow editing the "Include the full-text index" option?

Do you need to execute the option "Re-index site" or is it enough to "Re-index list"?
How I can check the full crawl has been successfully run on SharePoint online?

Am I missing something to remove this column in searches?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit display template to hide columns which you do not want to appear in search results.
More information here.
[Display templates](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/05/understand-how-item-display-templates-and-hit-highlighting-work-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx)

Comment: Can i modify result templates in Sharepoint Online?

Comment: Yes you can. For more information, click on link in answer.

Comment: @404 your link returns a 404 error ;). Display Templates are not recommended in a SharePoint Online environment because it only works with Classic Experience.


Link update:
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-display-templates

Answer (score 0):

A highly customizable solution for SharePoint Online is PNP Modern Search. With this WebParts it's possible to exclude any column from search

https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/

Comment: Lex, do you know how to do this within the PnP Modern Search?  Is it a feature for the new 4.x release or will it work with 3.x?  I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: Hi Gregg, I remember that is some columns like "Created by" are not customizable in SPO and can't be excluded from crawling. I used PnP Search Webpart only to remove the column from the search result view.